# Localizing concatenated or dynamic strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization

I'm familiar with using NSLocalizedString() to localize strings, but the problem I have today requires a little more finesse.  My situation is like this:

```
NSString *userName; //the users name, entered by the user.  Does not need localized
NSString *favoriteFood; //the users favorite food, also entered by user, and not needing localized

NSString *summary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s favorite food is %@", userName, favoriteFood];
```

This works fine for english, but not every language uses the same word ordering as English, for example, a word-by-word translation of the same sentance from Japanese into English would read:

> UserName's favorite food pizza is

Not to mention that 's is doesn't make a possessive in every language.

What techniques are available for localizing this type of concatenated sentence?

UPDATE FOR THE BENEFIT OF OTHERS:
@Jon Reed is right, positional specifiers are very important to localization.  The document he linked only contains a reference to the fact that they can be used with NSString, NSLog, an others, the link doesn't really tell HOW to use them.

I found [this link](http://doc.dev.md/gawk/Printf-Ordering.html#Printf-Ordering), that explains it well.  It also explains my question better than I did.  From the link:

> Format strings for printf and sprintf
>   (see Printf) present a special problem
>   for translation. Consider the
>   following:1
>
> ```
>  printf(_"String `%s' has %d characters\n",
>            string, length(string))) A possible German
> ```
>
> translation for this might be:
>
> ```
>  "%d Zeichen lang ist die Zeichenkette `%s'\n" The problem
> ```
>
> should be obvious: the order of the
>   format specifications is different
>   from the original! Even though gettext
>   can return the translated string at
>   runtime, it cannot change the argument
>   order in the call to printf.
>
> To solve this problem, printf format
>   specifiers may have an additional
>   optional element, which we call a
>   positional specifier. For example:
>
> ```
>  "%2$d Zeichen lang ist die Zeichenkette `%1$s'\n" Here, the
> ```
>
> positional specifier consists of an
>   integer count, which indicates which
>   argument to use, and a ‘$’. Counts are
>   one-based, and the format string
>   itself is not included. Thus, in the
>   following example, ‘string’ is the
>   first argument and ‘length(string)’ is
>   the second:
>
> ```
>  $ gawk 'BEGIN {
>  >     string = "Dont Panic"
>  >     printf _"%2$d characters live in \"%1$s\"\n",
>  >                         string, length(string)
>  > }'
>  -| 10 characters live in "Dont Panic"
> ```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To specify order of substitution, use `%1$@` and `%2$@` as your format specifiers. The localized format string can use them in any order. For example, say your string key is "FavoriteFood". Call

```
NSString *summary =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"FavoriteFood", nil), 
                                       userName, favoriteFood];
```

The localization places the format specifiers wherever it makes sense for its locale. Example:

```
"FavoriteFood" = "%2$@ is the favorite food of %1$@";
```

See [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: I followed your link, and read Localizing String Resources (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html)  also.

I didn't see any reference to the format specifiers you mention (%2$@)  Can you explain that a little bit please?

Comment: Follow the link, and search for "positional specifiers". Also, give it a try. This is an essential tool for localization.

Comment: The `%$1@` should be `%1$@` at the end of your example.

Comment: @Jon Reid, I am unable to compile NSString* aText = [NSLocalizedString(@"FavoriteFood", nil), userName, favoriteFood]; Am I missing something? thx

Comment: @HussainSaleem Wow, not sure how I missed that. :-P I've updated the example.

Comment: Great, I didn't want to edit the code first. I thought I had to include some sort of a magic framework ;)

Answer (score -1):

Applying `NSLocalizedString()` to the format string `@"%@'s favorite food is %@"` should allow it to be replaced with the proper word order and possessives for the local language.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand NSLocalizedString.  How does it allow the order of the substitution variables to be changed?

Comment: @SooDesuNe, I don't think it does; but your example doesn't have that problem.  Are there any languages that put the object before the subject?  Wikipedia tells me there are a few native Brazilian languages, and Klingon... maybe it's not such a big deal?

Comment: @SooDesuNe: as in Jon Reid's answer, you can use position-specific string-format specifiers to take care of the ordering issue.

Comment: @ZaneClaes: No, "Atticus's" is the correct possessive singular according to the Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: Oops, I used a poor example, sorry; but the point still stands. A better example is **Joneses**. The rule applies to plural-possessives, such that it becomes **Joneses'** and not **Joneses's**.